# Inner Resistance of TRIAC

Tags: triac, thyristor

Due to some problems in my project, I am curious about the inner resistance of TRIAC when it turns on. I have run some tests. The setup is just like the schematic picture.

Rs is the source resistance with about 160 ohm. Rg is about 50 ohm. The trigger voltage Vtr is about 2.5V. Then with different input voltage Vs, the inner resistance Rt (resistance between MT1 and MT2) of triac when turning on seems to be varied.

Vs = 20Vpp 1kHz Sine wave, then Rt = 13.8 ohm

Vs = 5Vpp 1kHz Sine wave, then Rt = 26.5 ohm

Vs = 0.5Vpp 1kHz Sine wave, then Rt = 56.2 ohm

Vs = 4V DC, then Rt = 31.1 ohm

My question is that are these values of Rt quite normal? I mean is it the normal case that the inner resistance of TRIAC is about tens ohm and it would decrease with the increasing of Vs. Thank you very much.

(The TRIAC I used is Z0107MN)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxoPNi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in any doubt, read the datasheet! Fig. 12 gives the (typical, not guaranteed) I/V characteristics.

[image]

From this you can see that the triac in the on-state for currents >= 200 mA behaves like a constant-voltage drop of 0.7 - 1.1 V (temperature dependent), plus  a series resistor of ¬ 0.33 Ohm. This is the behaviour that you should expect.

(some of) You experiment uses very low currents, which is not what this component is designed for. The latching current can be as high as 20mA, hence the component should not be used below that current.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have one more question, if I keep on supplying the continuous trigger voltage to the TRIAC, can the TRIAC work even the current is low, maybe lower than the holding current?

Comment: Outside the specs anything is possible. My guess is that it would, but I would hesitate to base a product on this assumption.

Comment: @billyzhao Yes, it should work provided you supply enough gate current to turn it on in the relevant quadrants (in particular note that **negative** gate drive is typically preferable, and sometimes required  to get guaranteed turn-on). You will be measuring linearized  dynamic resistance  as there will be  an offset voltage.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you. But just like the schematic picture, I was keeping 2.5V DC to the gate of TRIAC all the time. The resistance is still much larger than the datasheet description. What would be the problem?

Comment: Might be due to how or what you are measuring. Oscilloscope? Voltmeter?

Comment: "and it would decrease with the increasing of Vs" that is exactly what you would expect because there is a (more or less) fixed voltage drop component (in addition to a more-or-less resistive component).

Comment: @billyzhao The gate should be driven by a current. As Wouter says, the voltage drop will not behave like a linear resistor, as a MOSFET would.

Answer (score 0):

When the TRIAC current drops below the holding current yes, the TRIAC will go open. But you have a continuous gate drive so there I am not quite sure what will happen. But the gate drive does not appear very high. You want to try a few TRIACs and over temperatures as you are probably operating down in areas with device to device variations.